# Django filter objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am fetching the users who did login today as follows:

```
today_login_count= User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()
```

I want to further filter results and fetch only those users whose username starts with yg_

How can I modify my code?

Comment: You've already discovered the `__startswith` extension... what isn't working for you?..

Comment: Is __contains more apt here? like username__contains='yg_'

Comment: Well no... because that doesn't do what you want it to do... although, why don't you try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this

```
count = User.objects.filter(last_login__year=timezone.now().year, 
      last_login__month=timezone.now().month,
      last_login__day=timezone.now().day,
      username__startswith='yg_').count()
```