# Django view fetching data from two models in a single query

Tags: django, django-views

I have **two** tables in my database which are relevant for this problem:

**exercise_state** with following fields:

```
| id | intensity_level | progress | exercise_id | user_id | current_date | user_rating |
```

**auth_user** with following fields:

```
| id | password | last_login | is_superuser | username | first_name | last_name | email | is_staff | is_active | date_joined |
```

Right now I am fetching some data in my view as follows:

```
def get_specific_exercise_finish_count(request, exerciseId):
    # Number of users who completed a specific exercise
    specific_exercise_finish_count = Exercise_state.objects.filter(exercise_id=exerciseId, intensity_level=7).count()

    data = {}
    data['count'] = specific_exercise_finish_count

    return JSONResponse(data)
```

Now I want to filter those results further for specific set of usernames i.e. usernames those starts with 'yg_' (I have two sets of usernames registered in my system one group starts with 'yg' and the other with 'yg_'). As username is not a field of *exercise_state*, I am not sure how to proceed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244058/django-filter-objects)

Comment: It was my question, that's correct. But there I am fetching data directly from the user table which has 'username' field. Here It's more like cross table query.

Comment: Ah right ok, by the looks of the query you've shown here, there isn't any relationship between the models. you should change that as per the docs, then your question becomes trivial

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with following code of piece, see the extra part in filter statement:

```
def get_specific_exercise_finish_count_memoryGames(request, exerciseId):
    # Number of users who completed a specific exercise
    specific_exercise_finish_count_memoryGames = Exercise_state.objects.filter(exercise_id=exerciseId, intensity_level=7, user__username__startswith='yg_').count()

    data = {}
    data['count'] = specific_exercise_finish_count_memoryGames

    return JSONResponse(data)
```